# Can snippets contain PHP?

Tags: php, snippets

The documentation says:

> Snippets are expanded at a very early stage on each template, making
>   it possible for them to hold dynamic content, ExpressionEngine tags,
>   other variables, **PHP**, etc.

The evidence seems to run contrary to that statement.

Can PHP be used in a snippet as it can in an embed when enabled?

The scenario: I have Google Analytics and other tracking code in a snippet. I want to wrap it in a simple PHP conditional to check for the live site URL, so I'm not hitting that code in my development/staging environment.

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as the template in which you put the snippet has PHP enabled.

Comment: Ah, the template that the snippet is rendered via, because the snippet is just merged in. Got it. As this is a snippet on every page, I'm better off with an embed if I want to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @low:can you please give me the syntax of including a snippet in my template?EE docs have only docs showing only embed syntax